# Deseralise an object that has property types

Tags: c#, json, object, request

I have this `JSON` response that is produced from a `POST` request that I have sent.

```json
{
    "correlationID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "scenarioID": 2,
    "scenarioIsAcceptedInPrinciple": false,
    "valid": false,
    "errors": [
        {
            "errorID": 90,
            "errorText": "For the 1st Employment of the 1st Applicant Please provide a valid Landline"
        },
        {
            "errorID": 22,
            "errorText": "The provided value 'string' is not a valid value for the property 'applicants[0][email]'"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to deserialize it so I can get the `errorID` and `errorText` and do testing assertions to see if the correct error ID and text came back.

I have got it to work with:

```cs
public partial class postRequest
{
    public bool Valid { get; set; }
    public object Errors { get; set; }
}
```

and it returns all of the error, like this:

Standard Output:

```json
[
    {
        "errorID": 90,
        "errorText": "For the 1st Employment of the 1st Applicant Please provide a valid Landline"
    },
    {
        "errorID": 22,
        "errorText": "The provided value 'string' is not a valid value for the property 'applicants[0][email]'"
    }
]
```

How would I return just the error ID and error text?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should create another class for the error.

```
public class Error
{
    public string ErrorID { get; set; }
    public string ErrorText { get; set; }
}
```

And then use that in the other class:

```
public Error[] Errors { get; set; }
```

Finally you access the errors like:

```
response.Errors[0].ErrorID
```

Comment: Can you show the code to deserialize?

Comment: It's the same as you already have for the postRequest object, all objects in the json graph will automatically be deserialized, it's cascading by default.

Comment: I don't have any code - it's not my question. I'm asking you to improve your answer.

Comment: Aha, well the best approach depends on how he's getting the json. If he's using HttpClient there is GetFromJsonAsync(). Otherwise JsonSerializer.Deserialize() is a good alternative. He stated in the question that he's already got some code for that so I figured it was out of scope for the question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to deserialize it like this object :

```cs
public class JsonResponse
{
    public bool valid { get; set; }
    public List<Error> errors { get; set; }
}

public class Error
{
    public int errorID { get; set; }
    public string errorText { get; set; }
}
```

For deserialization:

```
var data =System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonResponse>("your json source");
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a list of errors, not just a one

```
List<Error> errors = JObject.Parse(json)["errors"].Select(x => x.ToObject<Error>()).ToList();
    
public class Error
{
    public int ErrorID { get; set; }
    public string ErrorText { get; set; }
}
```

you can see them

```
foreach (var error in errors)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error Id : {error.ErrorID}, Error Text {error.ErrorText}");
    }
    
    // or
    
    var errId=errors[0].ErrorID;
```